# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' error while importing the requests module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 OS while importing requests module in Interactive shell the below error is being noticed
Don't know why
I have installed requests using pip3
as below
pip3 install requests and when i try to uninstall requests using 
pip3 uninstall requests it goes good and even at installing it shows it has installed succesfully with version number

`

```
`>>> import requests


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 888, in _find_spec
AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 867, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 449, in spec_from_loader
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 216, in is_package
    return hasattr(self.__get_module(fullname), "__path__")
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import random
  File "/home/chaitu/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    n=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 184, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/home/chaitu/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    n=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 888, in _find_spec
AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 867, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 449, in spec_from_loader
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 216, in is_package
    return hasattr(self.__get_module(fullname), "__path__")
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/chaitu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import random
  File "/home/chaitu/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    n=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You named your own module `random.py`, and it's shadowing [the built-in `random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). The additional errors are caused by the error handling hook itself having errors, but it's ultimately caused by them expecting the built-in module and getting your unrelated module. Don't name-shadow built-in modules.

It looks like there is a further error where your own `random.py` tried to do `int(input())` and failed because it read nothing from `stdin`, but that's a fairly obvious error (either you entered nothing, or you launched it in such a way that `stdin` was closed).

Comment: Thank You 
I have deleted my module It worked But what it has to do with random module

Comment: @Chaitu - give the file name not associated with built-in library functions. Rename the `random.py` to `mod_random.py` something like that.

Comment: @chaitu: Your dependencies take a dependency on the built-in `random` module (for whatever reason). When they try to import it, and `random.py` is in the working directory, they get your `random.py`, not the one that ships with Python, and is missing all the classes and function they expect.